# adding ORDER BY decreases speed by 15x

Tags: mysql

I have a simply query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT images.* 
FROM   `images` 
WHERE  `images`.`user_id` IN (SELECT following_id 
                                FROM   `follows` 
                                WHERE  `follows`.`follower_id` = 9 
                                       AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1) 
LIMIT  15 offset 0
```

This executes in less than 1 ms.

Adding an ORDER BY on column that is indexed:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT images.* 
    FROM   `images` 
    WHERE  `images`.`user_id` IN (SELECT following_id 
                                    FROM   `follows` 
                                    WHERE  `follows`.`follower_id` = 9 
                                           AND `follows`.`accepted` = 1) 
ORDER  BY id DESC 
LIMIT  15 offset 0
```

takes 15 ms to execute. There are a mere 7,000 images in the table. Should it really take 15 fold time to order an indexed column? What can I do to decrease such a performance hit?

Running on:

```
Server version: 5.6.11-enterprise-commercial-advanced MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table       | type        | possible_keys                     | key                  | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                                        |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2> | ALL         | NULL                              | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                     | NULL | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | images    | ref         | user_id                           | user_id              | 5       | <subquery2>.following_id |    3 | NULL                                                         |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | follows     | index_merge | accepted,follower_id,following_id | follower_id,accepted | 5,2     | NULL                     |   19 | Using intersect(follower_id,accepted); Using where; Distinct |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: 14ms doesn't seem that bad for sorting 7k records

Comment: Also, you'll need to say what the schema and indexes look like on these tables.

Comment: Have you tried changing your query to one that does a JOIN?  Indexes on the `follows` table may help.

Comment: @climbage Yes, but eventually, I will be transferring over to 100k records (I haven't tried yet), so that's why I am worried.

Comment: @ta.speot.is thanks! that's fixed the performance hit. Now ORDER BY is actually faster than without it.

Comment: How long does it take if you omit the qualifier DESC?

Comment: @WalterMitty .7ms to 1.1 ms

Comment: Well, you have to sort it and obviously that's going to take some time. But have you tried asking your users whether they can even _notice_ a 15ms difference? There seems little point in optimising something that's undetectable.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes I know 15 ms is really fast, but soon I will be working with database of 100k rows so that's why the 15 fold difference worries me.

Comment: Try it with 100,000 records and see the impact. You'll possibly find it's less than you think. It's a given that performance-testing DB queries should be done on hardware/software/data that matches what you'll see in production.

Comment: Add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the 2 tables.

Comment: You probably do not have an index on `(accepted, follower_id, following_id)`, that's why you get the `Using intersect(follower_id,accepted); Using where; Distinct`

Answer (score 3):

> Should it really take 15 fold time to order an indexed column?

Well it depends where this column is being used. Just because it's indexed (and presumably in some order) doesn't mean that using it in a query will magically make it fast.

Assume there are two indexes in the table, for `id` (ordered by `id`) and for `user_id` (ordered by `user_id`). If MySQL uses the latter to quickly look up the rows that satisfy the `WHERE` predicate then the result is that it might have all the rows in `user_id` order.

You want them in `id` order, so MySQL has to order them. Your previous query didn't have to do ordering. It should come as no surprise that `more work == more time`.

> What can I do to decrease such a performance hit?

Look at the execution plan. MySQL has `EXPLAIN`.

You should also make your queries as simple as you can. I assume your `images` table has a primary key, so the `DISTINCT` in `SELECT DISTINCT images.* FROM images ...` doesn't really make sense.

Also by taking all the columns (`images.*`) you're forcing MySQL to acquire every attribute for each row that is returned, whereas being more selective (no pun intended) with your columns might result in less data needing to be returned. Simplifying somewhat: less columns gives MySQL an opportunity to satisfy the query using only small indexes, rather than the table data.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the fact that the inner query may present several repeated 'following_id' wouldn't cause the records from images to appear several times? The DISTINCT in this case makes at least some sense. Also, in order to avoid this, couldn't the DISTINCT clause be moved to the inner query instead?

Comment: @OnoSendai That's not how `IN` works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f5de/1/0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the index on id sorts in the ascending direction, but your ORDER BY is asking for the data in the descending direction.  Your ORDER BY has to ask for the data in DESC direction so that the LIMIT clause will give you the rows you want.

I do not know whether MY SQL supports descending indexes or not.  If it does, try adding a descending index on id and see what that does to your performance.  In addition, the comments warning you against predicting performance in production based on tests with small sample data are good ones.  You need to conduct a mre realistic test before you can predict real world preformance.